# Specifying a target in a makefile without having it show up in $^

Tags: makefile

I have a program that links against a a library that is also in the process of development. I want to re-link my program when the library changes (and therefore have the `.a` file in my list of prerequisites, but I also want to be able to use the `$^` automatic variable (or something like it) to list all of the *other* targets in the invocation of the linker. I may also list the makefile itself as a dependency for some targets, to ensure they get recompiled if I change the makefile.

Is there some way I can flag a particular file as a dependency without having it show up in automatic variables like `$^`?

Comment: I don't think so, but isn't `$(filter-out %.a, $^)` good enough?

Comment: @Beta: I didn't know about `filter-out`. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to modify `$^` itself, but GNUMake has some good [functions for manipulating text](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions), such as `filter-out`:

```
foo: bar baz quartz.a Makefile
    @echo I want $(filter-out %.a Makefile, $^), not $(filter %.a Makefile, $^)
```